# How to do screencast with animated presentations

Tags: screencasts

Here is a snapshot of a screencast I was watching:

[image]

How do you create such animated presentation in a screencast? I know how to capture stuff I am doing on my computer as screencast, but how do you build a dynamic presentation? What are the tools available for a Mac user?

Answer (score 0):

#### [Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia/)

has versions for both Windows and [OS X](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia/features/mac/) although the OS X version doesn't offer that many features. You could take a look at the free trial and see if it works out for you. I think it's a decent software.

[image]

#### [Snapz Pro X](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/snapzprox/)

is a dedicated OS X screencasting software and comes at $69. It also has some nice features but might not be the right thing for you.

#### [SMART Software](http://smarttech.com/us/Support/Browse+Support/Download+Software)

is specialized on note-taking for classes, meetings and presentations. We used it at University. It allows you to write on your screen with digital ink by using a graphics tablet or a touchscreen.